# Print array every 1 second

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a game that loops through an array every 1 second and then when the 'x' key is pressed the array stops printing, and the next 'x' key press the array resumes from the current element and loops again. my game starts with x and if i press again it just prints every 1 second. how do i add functionality and keep track of cards in the deck

My program is in java frame

```
public class Game {

private JFrame frame;
public static String[] cards = { "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Menu window = new Menu();
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);

                //timer for card loops
                timer.schedule(new GoCards(cards), 0, 1000);

                window.frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
                    {
                        char key = e.getKeyChar();

                        if(key == 'x')
                        {                           
                            //pause the timer and if i press again then resume timer
                            timer.cancel();
                        }


                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}

class GoCards extends TimerTask
{
    String[] deck;

    public GoCards(String[] cards)
    {
        deck = cards;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yours is a Swing program, so you should use a `javax.swing.Timer` or a "Swing" Timer, not a `java.util.Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a Swing application, so no, don't use `Thread.sleep(...)`, not unless you want to risk putting your entire GUI to sleep, and don't use a `java.util.Timer`, since this does not work well with the Swing event thread. Instead you will want to use the tool best suited for the job -- a Swing Timer, aka `javax.swing.Timer`. The Timer can be started by calling `start()` on it and stopped simply by calling `stop()`, and you set the delay in milliseconds in its constructor. Also, use of a KeyListener is risky as it won't work if anything, such as a JButton for instance, steals the focus. Better to use Key Bindings. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a timer such as wait

```
Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
```

Then keep track of each key press / iteration with a new counter n.

Checking for key presses would be a matter of simply handling them as they come in, or something as arbitrary as checking each iteration for any particular key.

Comment: I put `Thread.sleep(1000);` inside the array loop of GoCards.run and it prints every 1 second now. but how do i make the thread to pause because if i use `timer.cancel()` i dont know the card that was stopped on. if i know the card it stops on i can start a new task and start printing from that card

Comment: You'd want to compensate for that by placing in the propper checks. For example, if key x is pressed. you'd want to have some method for checking the current card and placing it in memory. rather then simply moving through the loop